# Tomcat classloading issue

Tags: tomcat, classloader

I have 2 applications in the same Tomcat (8.0.14) instance. Both war files contain the same jar file, but of different versions. 
As I see both applications use the jar file from the second application. I thought that tomcat provides different classloaders for the 2 applications. Unfortunately I could not find any documentation explaining this issue. Is it a bug or expected behaviror?

Jars are located

```
APP1
  WEB-INF
    LIB
      lib-version1.jar

APP2
  WEB-INF
    LIB
      lib-version2.jar
```

**Update**:
The classloading worked pefectly. The issue I experienced and seemed to be a classloading problem was cause by something else

Comment: Where are your jars located?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559210/just-how-tomcat-classloader-separate-different-webapps-object-scope-in-same-jvm

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat do have different `ClassLoader`s for applications, to be precise:

```
    Bootstrap
        |
     System
        |
     Common
     /     \
Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
```

Source: [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

Maybe you have put your classes into `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, which is loaded by the Common `ClassLoader`, and this causes this.