# What are differences between these kinds of reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

```
String s =  "something";
Class<?> c1 = s.getclass();
Class<?> c2 = Class.forname("java.lang.String");
Class<?> c3 = java.lang.String.class;
```

What is different between c1, c2, c3?

If I load a class with  different class-loader, there will be different class of that class in runtime.

```
Classloader cl1 = new URLClassloader(...) ;
Classloader cl2 = new URLClassloader(...) ;

Class<?> x1 = Class.forname("java.lang.String", cl1);
Class<?> x2 = Class.forname("java.lang.String", cl2);
```

x1  and x2  are not the same why?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of search would give you the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19559463/13745944

As said by Matthias: "if a class is loaded by two different class loaders, this class exists twice within the VM" therefore x1 is different from x2 because you're using different class loaders.

There's no difference between the c1, c2, c3 cause they use the same class loader.

Comment: This should be a comment / close vote instead.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new on the stack.