# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, lucene

In my project I'm using neo4j version 2.2.5 and it conflicts with `lucene` dependency in `pom.xml`, because I checked same code without `lucene` dependency and it was fine, so how can I use `lucene` and `neo4j` in same project without conflict.

ERROR:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, E:\neo4j
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
>       at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:108)
>       at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:95)
>       at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
>       at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:67)
>       at neo4j.graphdbtest.IndexSearchExample.initDB(IndexSearchExample.java:42)
>       at com.sessa.col.spr.act.process_flow.Flow.startProcess(Flow.java:56)
>       at com.sessa.col.spr.act.process_flow.FlowHandler.main(FlowHandler.java:17)
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@17973d6f' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:489)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:106)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:331)
>       ... 8 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/document/Fieldable
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.NodeRangeDocumentLabelScanStorageStrategy.(NodeRangeDocumentLabelScanStorageStrategy.java:71)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newKernelExtension(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:73)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newKernelExtension(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:39)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:66)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483)
>       ... 11 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 16 more

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sessa.col.spr.act</groupId>
<artifactId>Color-Spreading-Activation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Color-Spreading-Activation</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparsity</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkseejava</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not possible to use Neo4j and latest version of Lucene in one Maven project. Neo4j is using version 3.6.

You have two options

1. Write your own Class Loader

   - [Java Class Loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540150/java-class-loaders)
2. Use Maven Shade plugin

   - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
   - https://github.com/lagodiuk/neo4j-uber-jar/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I used shading but couldn't solve the problem. Again got same exceptions. I am using neo4j 2.2.5 version, and in shading I am using lucene 3.6.2 I guess it should be solution. But the result is weird.

Comment: Do I have to make new empty maven project with shaded dependency and add it to my build path in my main maven project?